# Nefness of tangent bundle of co-tangent bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective Fano manifold with Picard number one. Assume that $TX$ is nef.

Question: Is $T(T^*X)$  nef ?

Comment: What do you mean by that?  Are you asking whether the tensor product of the tangent bundle with the cotangent bundle is a nef bundle on $X$?  The total space of the cotangent bundle over $X$ is only quasi-projective, so what (precisely) do you mean by "nef" for a bundle over this quasi-projective manifold?

Comment: Consider the embedding  $T^*X \subset \mathbb{P}(T^*X \oplus \mathcal{O})$. Then I am asking nefness of $\iota_*T(T^*X)$, where $\iota$ is the inclusion. The answer is negative. I got the proof of it.